# Applying the random function for every row in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make a google sheet that assigns a random alphanumeric sequence to every new row added. However, when I use the rand() function within the array formula the outputs are all the same. I'm wondering if there is any way in order to call RANDALPHA() - a custom function - for each row.

[image]

This is what RANDALPHA is from: https://yagisanatode.com/2018/08/23/google-sheets-random-alphabetic-random-alphanumeric-and-random-alphanumeric-character-custom-functions/

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A:A="";;RANDARRAY(ROW(A:A))))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IF(A:A="",,SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 CHAR(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(""&RANDARRAY(ROWS(A:A), 15)*(10^15), JOIN("|", 
 SORT({ROW(48:57); ROW(65:90); ROW(97:122)}, 1, ))), 48))),,9^9)), " ", )))
```

[image: 0]

```
ROW(48:57)  = 0-9
ROW(65:90)  = A-Z
ROW(97:122) = a-z
RANDARRAY(ROWS(A:A), 15)*(10^15) - the first 15 is equal to the length 
                                   of randomly generated sequence
```

---

on the other hand, if you are happy with chaos instead of a random chance you can do:

```
=INDEX(IF(A:A="",,SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CHAR(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(""&
 TEXT(PI()^EXP(1*PI())*SEQUENCE(ROWS(A:A), 15, 17, 17)^10, "#"), JOIN("|", 
 SORT({ROW(48:57); ROW(65:90); ROW(97:122)}, 1, ))), 48))),,9^9)), " ", )))
```

[image]

which won't recalculate at all while you edit your sheet

or if you prefer newly generated values every day:

```
=INDEX(IF(A:A="",,SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(CHAR(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(""&
 TEXT(TODAY()*PI()^EXP(1*PI())*SEQUENCE(ROWS(A:A), 15, 17, 17)^10, "#"), JOIN("|", 
 SORT({ROW(48:57); ROW(65:90); ROW(97:122)}, 1, ))), 48))),,9^9)), " ", )))
```

Comment: Sorry, I clarified what I was trying to do above but this also helps. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidChoi answer updated. you can drop your script and use just a formula

Comment: is there any way to keep the results permanent?

Comment: @DavidChoi answer extended

Answer (score 1):

I wish I understood exactly how INDEX works in @player0's answer, but anyway, while playing with it trying to understand it, and copying his use of RANDARRAY, I found that ARRAYFORMULA somehow also works.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A:A),RANDARRAY(ROW(A:A),1),""))
```

[image]

Comment: `INDEX()` is used instead of `ARRAYFORMULA()` just because it has fewer characters